# Batch Normalization in tensorflow 2.0 makes prediction results worse

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have built a CNN with the following architecture:

```
X = self.conv_layer_1(inputs)
X = self.conv_layer_2(X)
X = self.max_pool_1(X)
X = self.dropout_1(X,training = training)
X = self.batch_norm_1(X,training = training)

X = self.conv_layer_3(X)
X = self.conv_layer_4(X)
X = self.max_pool_2(X)
X = self.dropout_2(X,training = training)
X = self.batch_norm_2(X,training = training)

X = self.flatten(X)
X = self.dense_1(X)
X = self.batch_norm_3(X,training = training)
X = self.dropout_3(X)
X = self.softmax(X)

return X
```

If I don't use a batch_normalization layers, I am getting good accuracy (train 95%, test 79 %).  If I use only `self.batch_norm_3`, then the result is getting worse and from time to time, on test sets, the loss increases dramatically (like every 3-4 epochs it goes from 1.23123 to 500000).

If I use `self.batch_norm_1` and/or `self.batch_norm_2`, I always get an accuracy of 10% test and train).

Why is this happening?

I have used the CIFAR-10 dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361700/lack-of-batch-normalization-before-last-fully-connected-layer) could help you understand.

Please note - Dense layer is a FC layer which is further used for predictions, there is no need to standardise its outputs.
Standardisation and hence batchnorm is useful when there is a large variation in the input data (also called as covariate shift) which further creates an imbalanced input data for further CNN layers.